# Akka.net waiting for multiple pieces of data

Tags: c#, actor, akka.net

This is a common scenario I run into, where I have two (or more) actors getting some data asynchronously, and then I need to do an operation when they're all finished.

What is the common pattern to do this?

Here's a simplified example.

```
public MasterActor : ReceiveActor
{
     public MasterActor() 
     {
          Initialize();
     }

     public void Initiaize()
     {
         Receive<DoSomeWork>(_ => 
         {
              var actor1 = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new Actor1());
              var actor2 = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new Actor2());

              // pretend these actors send responses to their senders
              // for sake of example each of these methods take between 1 and 3 seconds
              actor1.Tell(new GetActor1Data());
              actor2.Tell(new GetActor2Data());
         });

        Receive<Actor1Response>(m => 
        {
             //actor 1 has finished it's work
        });

        Receive<Actor2Response>(m => 
        {
             //actor 2 has finished it's work
        });
     }
}
```

To kick this off I send the `MasterActor` a `DoSomeWork` message.

What is the common way to do an operation when I have both a `Actor1Response` and an `Actor2Response`.

I don't really want to have logic in each receive handler checking if the other one is finished or anything like that.  I guess what i'm thinking of something similar to a `Task.WaitAll()` method.

Am I just attacking the problem the wrong way?  Do I need to re-write the actors in a different way?

Any common patterns or solutions would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common solution for that is attaching some kind of correlation id shared by both request and response messages - since actor processes messages synchronously, this could be unchecked int/long counter.

You simply store correlation ids in some data structure (let say set) inside the caller, and when response is received, remove it's correlation id from set. `WaitAll` finishes basically when set is empty or timeout occurs.

You can set timeout by using `Context.SetReceiveTimeout(timeout)`, this way actor will send a `ReceiveTimeout` method to itself after it haven't received any message for some time.

This behavior is pretty generic and may be abstracted quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be to increment a "vote" count on the master when each child replies. When vote == child count, you're done.

You could extend this so as to only count the first message from each child, or a specific message from each child, but it all boils down to counting in the end.